# change code for angular-ui-router 2.0.13

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I created this plnkr for show some code that i have to correct.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rlKFW2DIqzVSaWTt79u5?p=catalogue

I think i have to change the code inside stateProvider

```
validationApp.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
```

With the latest version of ui-router(2.0.13) I can't see the login mask and the pages when I make the admin page when i make loginlogin.
I'm working on ui-router v2.0.7 with no problems, but i want to correct my code for the latest version, someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your issue, but at least here you can see the working [versin of your plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/4tMKgAaNhZSmLcTaBARY?p=preview)

I changed the index.html

```
//<div ui-view="index"></div>
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

*Also I added links to angular and ui-router... and it is working now.*

This is the script.js snippet, which targets the unnamend view *(not ui-view="index")* - that's why I changed the index.html

```
validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', [
  'ui.router'
])

validationApp.config(['$urlRouterProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.when( '' ,  '/login' );

    $urlRouterProvider.when( '/admin' ,  '/admin/home');

}])

validationApp.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            //templateUrl: 'views/partials/login.html',
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl',
            authNotRequired:true
        })
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4tMKgAaNhZSmLcTaBARY?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I found the error, i have to delete body tag in the other sub pages.